# How to exit a Python process if any parallel thread exits?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a python process with a main thread starting parallel threads for 1 gRPC server and 1 HTTP server. I want the OS process for this application to exit if ANY of the parallel threads exits.

I think the main thread, as is coded here, would wait as long as there is a single parallel thread that is running. What do I need to do to change this so the main thread exits as soon as any parallel thread exits?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  svc = MyService()
  t1 = GrpcServer(svc)
  t1.start()
  t2 = HealthHttpServer()
  t2.start()
```

with the servers defined as

```
class GrpcServer(threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self, service):
    super().__init__()
    self.grpcServer(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10))
    self.grpcServer.add_insecure_port('[::]:8000')
    myservice_pb2_grpc.add_MyServiceServicer_to_server(service, self.grpcServer)

  def run(self):
    self.grpcserver.start()

class HealthServer(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        port=2113
        httpd = HTTPServer(('localhost', port), HealthHTTPRequestHandler)
        httpd.serve_forever()

class HealthHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        '''Respond to a GET request.'''
        if self.path == '/healthz':
            self.send_response(HTTPStatus.OK)
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(b'ok')
        else:
            self.send_response(HTTPStatus.NOT_FOUND)
            self.end_headers()
```

Comment: Call your OS 'terminateProcess() API?

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest I've found so far is:

- define all these threads as [daemon threads](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects)
- define a global [threading.Event](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#event-objects)
  object
- add a top-level try...finally in each thread, and call that event' set()
  in the finally
- in the main thread wait on that event after the threads are started

If anything goes wrong in any of the threads the finally block will execute, signaling that event, unblocking the main thread which exits. All the other threads being daemon threads, the process will then exit.